# Код INSERT содержащий все значения таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть заполненная таблица. Можно ли получить код INSERT содержащий все значения таблицы? Т.е. есть таблица

```
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | name            |
+-----+-----------------+
|  1  | Ivan Ivanov     |
|  2  | Sergey Petrov   |
+-----+-----------------+
```

Нужно получить из нее код вида:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(1, Ivan Ivanov)
INSERT INTO table VALUES(2, Sergey Petrov)
```

Возможно ли это?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/85186/4827341

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('INSERT INTO table VALUES(', id, ',\'', name, '\')')
                           SEPARATOR ';\n')
INTO OUTFILE 'c://folder/filename.sql'
FROM `table`;
```

Comment: В вопросе указан тег `sql-server`. А функция group_concat есть только в MySQL, так же как и into outfile

Comment: Да group_concat тут на самом необязателен, ничто не мешает сливать строки в файл по одной. И выгрузка в файл у MS SQL есть, пусть и синтаксически запрос будет выглядеть иначе. Да, внимания на тег не обратил, верно. Ну получилась демонстрация идеи, а не готовый код. Бывает.

Answer (score -2):

Ну ты можешь увидеть команды через импорт базы либо программно сделать вывод

Comment: а можно подробнее, как это сделать?

Comment: В Management Studio с помощью команды "Генерация скрипта".

Comment: @msi где находится эта команда?

Comment: t16bz, правой кнопкой по имени базы.

Comment: @msi нет такого

Comment: Задачи -> Сформировать скрипты->...